# Exportar script de workbench a phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Estoy haciendo una sistema para un evento sin fines de lucro. La idea es crear grupos de 15 personas y generarles sus gafetes con su hotel, haitación y en que autobús les va tocar. 
 Genere una BD, pero me esta marcando muchos errores.
    La hice en MYSQL Work bench y al momento de pasar el script al phpmyadmin me `introducir el código aquí`genero muchos errores.

```
    ERRORES

    [Análisis estático:

    Se encontraron 3 errores durante el análisis.

    Se esperaba una coma o un corchete de cierre. (near "VISIBLE" at position 480)
    Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "`registros_id`" at position 539)
    Tipo de declaración desconocida. (near "REFERENCES" at position 555)
    consulta SQL:
`healtha2_iyfprueba`.`grupos` -- ----------------------------------------------------- CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `healtha2_iyfprueba`.`grupos`( `idgrupos` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `nombregrupos` VARCHAR(255) NULL, `tipogrupos` VARCHAR(255) NULL, `registros_id` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`idgrupos`, `registros_id`), INDEX `fk_grupos_registros_idx`(`registros_id` ASC) VISIBLE, CONSTRAINT `fk_grupos_registros` FOREIGN KEY(`registros_id`) REFERENCES `healtha2_iyfprueba`.`registros`(`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION ) ENGINE = InnoDB

    MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

    #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'VISIBLE,
        CONSTRAINT `fk_grupos_registros` FOREIGN KEY(`registros_id`) REFER' en la linea 10]
```

Comment: postea las lineas que te muestra el archivo o crea una conexion a la db en el workbrench y generala desde ahí

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen ligeras diferencias entre MySQL respecto a MariaDB y Workbench generará el código SQL para MySQL Server, caso distinto a PHPMyAdmin en el que entiende muy bien el código para MariaDB Server.

Sin embargo es fácil de arreglar.

Elimina todas las palabras `VISIBLE`, por ejemplo

```
INDEX `idtable` (`idtable` ASC) VISIBLE,
```

por

```
INDEX `idtable` (`idtable` ASC),
```

Si estas usando MariaDB cambia esto otro también (posiblemente si el servidor es MySQL no haya que cambiarlo)

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `nombre_de_tu_DB` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
```

por

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `nombre_de_tu_DB` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
```